# How to use chi square table in python with only row and column?

Tags: python, chi-squared

I would like to know how I could obtain a value from the chi square table from the spicy library or any other library?
Example:
I want the value of `row = 1`, and `column = 0.05`:

[image: Table IMG]

And I receive the value shown in the image that is `= 3.8415`

Or is there some other way to get it?

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare

row = 1
column = 0.05

print( chisquare(( row, column )) )
```

Output

```
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=0.8595238095238096, pvalue=0.35387198439864465)
```

desired output:

```
3.8415
```

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't so clear about it, so I asked, however, I already edited the question.@Prune

Comment: You have `row = 1` and `column = 0.05`, then you hardcode values of 6 and 0.05.  6 is not very close to 1.

Comment: my mistake, I already edited it @TimRoberts

Comment: You haven't edited anything, as far as I can see.  The `chisqpare` function expects to get a list of observations.  From that list, it computes the p-value and the chi squared.  You don't give it v and p, you give it the set of observations and it computes those values.

Comment: For that reason the title and the explanation, because I do not want to use a list of values, I only want to obtain the value of the table as in excel inv.chicuad.cd is used, but as the first comment said to add code, well I added what I thought it was, but the result does not come out

Comment: By the way I already looked at the code and if I was right I forgot to use the values of the row and column, now if I made it run again I'm sorry @TimRoberts

Comment: If you want to look up values in a table, then you have to access a table.  Nowhere in your post have you attempted to load or access the table you show in that picture.  Please re-read the [documentation for `chisquare`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html), so you understand how your current code is flawed.

Comment: That's simply not how `scipy.stats.chisquare` works.

Comment: As indicated I would like to know how I can obtain a value from the chi square table, I do not know how to load the table, in excel I do not load the table I just use a function, I would like to do the same in python @Prune

Comment: So is there a way to do what I want? Because my question is how can I do that, my question was not ... how does this function work I am sorry@TimRoberts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is how to look up a chi-square critical value with known "degrees of freedom" value (rows in your image) and "significance level" (columns in your image).

You can accomplish this using the [`scipy.stats.chi2.ppf()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2.html) method:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2

deg_f = 1
sig = 0.05

# find critical value
chi2.ppf(1-sig, deg_f)
# 3.841458820694124
```